# How can I change, with jQuery, value of progress-pie-chart if user fills input text fields?

Tags: jquery, html, progress-bar

```js
$(function(){
  var $ppc = $('.progress-pie-chart'),
    percent = parseInt($ppc.data('percent')),
    deg = 360*percent/100;
  if (percent > 50) {
    $ppc.addClass('gt-50');
  }
  $('.ppc-progress-fill').css('transform','rotate('+ deg +'deg)');
  $('.ppc-percents span').html(percent+'%');
});
```

```css
.progress-pie-chart {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
  position: relative;
}
.progress-pie-chart.gt-50 {
  background-color: #81CE97;
}

.ppc-progress {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  top: calc(50% - 100px);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  clip: rect(0, 200px, 200px, 100px);
}
.ppc-progress .ppc-progress-fill {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  top: calc(50% - 100px);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  clip: rect(0, 100px, 200px, 0);
  background: #81CE97;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.gt-50 .ppc-progress {
  clip: rect(0, 100px, 200px, 0);
}
.gt-50 .ppc-progress .ppc-progress-fill {
  clip: rect(0, 200px, 200px, 100px);
  background: #E5E5E5;
}

.ppc-percents {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 173.91304px/2);
  top: calc(50% - 173.91304px/2);
  width: 173.91304px;
  height: 173.91304px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}
.ppc-percents span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2.6em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #81CE97;
}

.pcc-percents-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

.progress-pie-chart {
  margin: 50px auto 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="profile_general_gender" name="profile_general[gender]" required="required" value="Male" placeholder="Sesso" /> <br>
<input type="text" id="profile_general_firstname" name="profile_general[firstname]" required="required" value="Gianluca" placeholder="Nome" /> <br>
<input type="text" id="profile_general_lastname" name="profile_general[lastname]" required="required" value="Diodato" placeholder="Cognome" /> <br>
<input type="text" id="profile_general_role" name="profile_general[role]" required="required" value="Developer" placeholder="Ruolo" />
</div>

<div class="progress-pie-chart" data-percent="0">
  <div class="ppc-progress">
    <div class="ppc-progress-fill"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ppc-percents">
    <div class="pcc-percents-wrapper">
      <span>%</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to creating progress bar working with input text fields in a user details form but not working well. I can increment value but decrement fails. This is the example that I found:

[Review progress circular bar demo](http://codepen.io/shankarcabus/pen/GzAfb)

```
$(function(){
  var $ppc = $('.progress-pie-chart'),
    percent = parseInt($ppc.data('percent')),
    deg = 360*percent/100;
  if (percent > 50) {
    $ppc.addClass('gt-50');
  }
  $('.ppc-progress-fill').css('transform','rotate('+ deg +'deg)');
  $('.ppc-percents span').html(percent+'%');
});
```

I need my progress-pie-chart works on loading page because i fill any fields with values back from DB and if user wants to change any fields or add others.